# Steam: is it possible to use in-house streaming and record gameplay at the same time?

Tags: steam, windows-10, recording, steam-in-home-streaming

I am streaming from Windows 10 host to macOS client.

What sort of solution are available? I think I should capture on host to avoid unnecessary quality lost.

I would like some suggestions particularly for old games like *The Sims 1*, where Windows 10's built-in game bar / DVR doesn't seem to work.

Comment: please define 'doesn´t seem to work'. Do you get an error? Does the bar not pop-up? Does the recording not start? Does it work for you with other games?

Comment: Have you attempted to use a 3rd party software like Open Broadcaster Software? you could use this to record on either device.

Answer (score -1):

Using OBS to record the game while streaming will work.